# Css syntax for after element of a label

Tags: html, css

I'm creating some radio inputs whose labels have an after element. I have an after pseudo-element for the label. What is the CSS syntax to have a pseudo-element for all the labels except the last label? The method I know seems to not work. I am attaching my code below for reference

**CSS file:**

```
.switches-container {
  width: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}


.switches-container input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


.switches-container label {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.switches-container label:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.switch-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.77, 0, .175, 1);
}

.switches-container input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.switch-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(-174%);
}

.switches-container input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.switch-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.switches-container input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.switch-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(277%);
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-right: -10px;">
  <div class="switches-container">
    <input type="radio" id="ftwo" name="switchPlan" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="fthree" name="switchPlan" value="3" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" id="ffour" name="switchPlan" value="4" />

    <label for="ftwo">2</label>
    <label for="fthree">3</label>
    <label for="ffour">4</label>

    <div class="switch-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `.switches-container label:not(:last-of-type)::after` since **none** of the labels are the last child which is the switch wrapper div.#

Answer (score 0):

To set a CSS rule for the last `label` among other elements, use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead of `:last-child`. Your example below:

```css
.switches-container {
  width: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}


.switches-container input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


.switches-container label {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.switches-container label:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.switch-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.77, 0, .175, 1);
}

.switches-container input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.switch-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(-174%);
}

.switches-container input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.switch-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.switches-container input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.switch-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(277%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-right: -10px;">
  <div class="switches-container">
    <input type="radio" id="ftwo" name="switchPlan" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="fthree" name="switchPlan" value="3" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" id="ffour" name="switchPlan" value="4" />

    <label for="ftwo">2</label>
    <label for="fthree">3</label>
    <label for="ffour">4</label>

    <div class="switch-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
```